# method not found Google.apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService..ctor(Initializer)

Tags: vb.net, methods, void

I have a VB NET application that works correctly in the development environment(windows 8.1).

When I distributed to a computer with windows 7 operates properly.
But when distributed to a computer with Windows 10 I get this error.

> Method not found: Void
>   Google.apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService..ctor(Initializer).

The procedure that gives me error is as follows:

```
Try
  Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
  scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)
  Dim credential As UserCredential
  Dim cs As New ClientSecrets
  cs.ClientId = wclientId 
  cs.ClientSecret = wclientSecret
  credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(cs, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result
  Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
  initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
  initializer.ApplicationName = wapplicationName
  service = New CalendarService(initializer)
  clientIdAutenticado = wclientId
Catch ex As Exception
  Throw New Exception("autenticate:" & ex.Message & ":" & ex.StackTrace)
End Try
```